# Initialize SessionFactory with existing Hazelcast instance

Tags: java, hibernate, hazelcast

When my server first loads, it initializes Hazelcast and have an instance.

At a later point, it initializes Hibernate's SessionFactory configured to use Hazelcast has 2nd level cache.

The result is having 2 components that initializes HZ instances.

My question is: Is there a way to pass HZ instance to SessionFactory?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can share your named hazelcast instance with Hibernate SessionFactory by using **hibernate.cache.hazelcast.instance_name**

Here is how to configure named hazelcast instance.

```
Config config = new Config();
config.setInstanceName( "my-named-hazelcast-instance" );
```

please check [latest documentation](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/) for more info.

Comment: is there a way to set instance name in the xml configuration file?

Comment: I guess not, I read somewhere that it's only done via code to prevent confusion and misconfigurations.

Comment: You can set the instance-name through XML Configuration in 3.6 which is not released yet. https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/resources/hazelcast-config-3.6.xsd#L36

Comment: Nice! guess at this point I will wait for it to be released. Thanks!